# Powershell AD filtering on datetime

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm having some issues with getting my LDAP filter to work correctly using the `Get-ADUser` commandlet. I'm attempting to create a small script to search through all the users in AD and if their expiration date is over 30 days ago disable the user and move it to a disabled user OU.

So far I have the following:

```
$filterString = "
(&
    (AccountExpires>=1)
    (AccountExpires<=$([DateTime]::Now.ToFileTime()))
    (!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
)" -replace "`r`n"

$UsersToDisable = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filterString
if($UsersToDisable -ne $null) {
    #$UsersToDisable | Disable-ADAccount
    Write-Output "`n"
    Write-Output "The following users have been disabled as their accounts have expired"
    foreach ($user in $UsersToDisable){
        #Write-Output $user.UserPrincipalName
        Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties AccountExpirationDate | Select UserPrincipalName, AccountExpirationDate | Write-Output
        #Get-ADUser -Identity $user | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Disabled Users,DC=domain,DC=local"
        }
    }
```

Obviously the filter only selects stuff before todays date. I also tried to create a filter using

```
$then = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
```

However, I cant seem to find a way to integrate it into `$filterstring`. I can pull the data using `Get-ADUser -filter` but then the bitwise filter doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: For `$then`, just use `$then = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).ToFileTime()`. When using `-replace`, you must use regex syntax. So change to `-replace '\r?\n'`.

Comment: thank you very much @AdminOfThings that solved the issue, I thought I had tried every iteration of using $then but hadn't thought of including the ToFileTime in the inital set

for clarity for everyone else the final filter string now looks as follows

$then =  (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).ToFileTime()
$filterString = "
(&
 (AccountExpires>=1)
 (AccountExpires<=$then)
 (!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
)" -replace "\r?\n"

Comment: I would do `$then = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date.ToFileTime()`. the `.Date` sets this date to midnight instead of having the current time in there.

Comment: @Theo thanks for that that's a nice way of keeping that tidy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @AdminOfThings for your comment.

We can use below LDAP filter to get the list of AD users whose accounts are disabled 30 days ago.

```vb
$then = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date.ToFileTime() 
$filterString = "
(&
    (AccountExpires>=1)
    (AccountExpires<=$then)
    (!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
)" -replace "\r?\n"
$UsersToDisable = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filterString
```